# How to create a table with a fixed <thead> without jQuery/ in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have found multiple ways to accomplish this so far, but none of them supports a thead with multiple table rows. I have tried the `display: block` with `overflow: auto` option but that also does not support multiple table rows with `rowspam` and `colspam`. This codepen https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/LNQxNK is exactly what I am looking for, but I have no idea how jQuery works and therefore I am unable to understand what is going on. Does anyone know if it is possible to accomplish this with vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

It does not require JS, only CSS

Add this to the thead selector:

```
position sticky
top 0
background white
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the html of the codepen. It is possible to create the same DOM tree with `document.createElement()` and `document.appendChild()`. Create and append the elements one by one. Use the same rowspan and colspan as provided in the example. To set rowspan change the attribute of the same name.

```
...
const thead = document.createElement(`thead`);
table.appendChild(thead);

const tr = document.createElement(`tr`);
thead.appendChild(tr);

const th = document.createElement(`th`);
th.rowspan = 2;
tr.appendChild(th );

etc with each th ...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. However, I think I may not have been clear. I am not trying to recreate the table using JS. I am trying to stick the `thead` to the top whenever the user scrolls. For example, try scrolling the codepen.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the codepen you linked to just use CSS to make the header sticky:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoxpNJ

This is all you need:

```
thead
{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```